# Join two unrelated SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join two unrelated SQL SELECTS into one table.

I have tried JOINS, UNIONS, CROSS JOINS... please help :)

```
FRIST:

SELECT korisnici.ime, korisnici.prezime, dosje_osobe.datum_kreacije FROM `dosje_osobe` INNER JOIN korisnici ON dosje_`enter code here`osobe.korisnici_idkorisnici=korisnici.idkorisnici

RETURNS:

ime prezime datum_kreacije
John    Doe 2014-06-12

SECOND:

SELECT  kategorije_prek.naziv , prekrsaji.opis_prekrsaja  FROM kategorije_prek LEFT OUTER JOIN prekrsaji_has_kategorije_prek ON kategorije_prek.idkategorije_prek = prekrsaji_has_kategorije_prek.kategorije_prek_idkategorije_prek LEFT OUTER JOIN prekrsaji ON prekrsaji_has_kategorije_prek.prekrsaji_idprekrsaji=prekrsaji.idprekrsaji

RETURNS:

naziv   opis_prekrsaja
Krađa   Ukrao teniske loptice

RESULT needed:

ime  |    prezime  |    datum_kreacije   |     naziv   |     opis_prekrsaja
John      Doe           2014-06-12             Krađa         Ukrao teniske loptice
```

Comment: Is there more than one row in either table? If so, *how* do you want to join them? which row in table 1 should join to each row in table 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u mean that u want to select data from 2 tables

using left join will do the job

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.column=table2.colum
```

where

```
table1.column=table2.colum
```

means the 2 columns that will be the same and will be used as link between them

Answer (score 2):

Well, if nothing is connecting them, then use `cross join`.  This will give all combinations:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT k.ime, k.prezime, o.datum_kreacije
      FROM `dosje_osobe` o INNER JOIN
           korisnici k
           ON o.korisnici_idkorisnici = k.idkorisnici
     ) ko CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT k.naziv, p.opis_prekrsaja
      FROM kategorije_prek p LEFT OUTER JOIN
           prekrsaji_has_kategorije_prek ph
           ON k.idkategorije_prek = ph.kategorije_prek_idkategorije_prek LEFT OUTER JOIN
           prekrsaji p
           ON ph.prekrsaji_idprekrsaji = p.idprekrsaji
     ) kp;
```